# rails 2.3.5 with ruby 1.9.1p429 : incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

I tried the ruby hacks for utf8 (from : http://gist.github.com/273741) ... and I'm still getting the following error: 
ActionView::TemplateError (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8)

What is bizarre for me is that the same content if retrieved with a post action (searching the app with an html from) it is displaying well ... however, with get (using an html link) it telling that their is character incompatibility !

Do you have any idea where it comes from ? is there a rails/ruby patchs for this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem com from template encoding in UTF-8 not in ASCII, like attempts.

In Rails 3, there are a new configuration for that :

```
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Comment: is there a way to change (force) template encoding to utf8 in ruby 1.9.1 ?